# Trouble with extractRegex and Regexreplace formula

Tags: regex

I'm working in a database app that allows text formulas. There is a specific formula that will convert a number to text, but I want that text to match the format written on checks

> `ONE-HUNDRED-FIFTY-AND-5/100`

Below is an example of the formula and the result. For some reason the output on the formula is only

> `AND-5/100`

Any tips on what I need to do to make the rest of my formula work?

"Amount number" is the field in my database that I want to convert to text.

```
upper(regexReplace(numberToWords(extractRegex({Amount number},^.*(?=(\\.)))),\\s+,-)) AND extractRegex({Amount number},[^.]*$)/100
```

Output I'm getting is only `AND X/100` the first part of the formula is not showing up.

Comment: What is the formula ? and what does `^.*(?=(\\.)))),\\s+,-)` and `[^.]*$` do ?

Comment: The regex in there is messy.  I can see in the input, what do you want the output to be and I can adjust the regex to make that work

Comment: If the dollar amount is $150.05, I want the output to be "ONE HUNDRED FIFTY AND 5/100"

Comment: If the dollar amount is $150.05, I want the output to be "ONE HUNDRED FIFTY AND 5/100" The formula "number ToWords"  gives me "ONE HUNDRED FIFTY POINT FIVE" The regex is supposed to extract\return the first half of the written amount before the "POINT" then isolate\return the second half after the point and format it as "AND 5/100" the "^.*(?=....." is meant to isolate everything before and after the "POINT" As of now the only result I'm getting is "AND 5/100"